# Why does my list does not return the correct sum

Tags: c#, list

So Im trying to get the total sum of the chosen articles. I made 3 lists :
- The first is where I store the article price.
- The second is where I store the amount of the article chosen.
- The third list is where I store the final price of the article.
I want to get so the sum of the third list for the final price of all articles chosen. 
However the result I get is always the price of the first article chosen no matter how much other articles I add.

so the three lists start empty and each time an article is clicked the " List Objets_prix " add the article price and "List Counter" adds the amount of the article.

```cs
        public List<int> Counter = new List<int>();
        public List<float> Objets_prix = new List<float>();
        public List<float> Objets_prixTotal = new List<float>();

public void CalculPrixTotal()
        {
        int ListIndex;
        int PrixTotal;

            foreach (float p in Objets_prix)
            {
                ListIndex = Objets_prix.IndexOf(p);
                Objets_prixTotal[ListIndex]= p * Counter[ListIndex];
            }

            PrixTotal = Objets_prixTotal.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
            LabelPrixTotal.Text = PrixTotal.ToString();
        }
```

Im sur that the prices are successfully added to the List Objets_prix, and the same thing for the second list.

Comment: if you have two items of the same price, won't your `ListIndex` / `IndexOf` code find only the first index, and use the wrong count? it seems like having 3 lists is the error here - why not a `List<SalesRow>` where `SalesRow` *has* a `public int Count {get;set;}`, a `public decimal ItemPrice {get;set;}`, and a `public decimal TotalPrice => ItemPrice * Count;` (note: `float` is not appropriate for currency; and `int` *may or may not* be appropriate for a quantity)

Comment: If you really *really* want to use three lists, use a plain for-loop for the index

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess that is exactly the problem !!

Comment: @HansKeﬆing How so ?

Comment: @ShahidOd instead of looping through all prices, and getting an index hoping that there are no duplicates, just do a `for (int listIndex=0; listIndex < Objets_prix.Count; listIndex++)`